# RandomForest doesn't accept log() on RHS of formula

Tags: r

I have tried to log-transform variables on the RHS of the formula given to `RandomForest` and this returns an error (model `m1`). However, if the log is on the LHS, it is not a problem (model `m2`).

```
library(randomForest)
m1 = randomForest(mpg ~ log(wt)+cyl+disp, data = mtcars)
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'wt' not found

```
m2 = randomForest(log(mpg) ~ wt+cyl+disp, data = mtcars)
```

Other functions, such as `lm` for example do not have a problem with a log on the RHS.

```
m3 = lm(mpg ~ log(wt)+cyl+disp, data = mtcars)
```

Is there any workaround for this or do I have to transform the dataset?
I have tried using `I()`, but it returns an error as well.

```
m4 = randomForest(mpg ~ I(log(wt))+cyl+disp, data = mtcars)
```

> Error in unique(c("AsIs", oldClass(x))) : object 'wt' not found

Comment: Transforming the dataset seems like an easy workaround.

Comment: randomForest appears to do some hacky things with the formula that suggest you're going to have to do the workaround.